# CSS Scale animation floats in from top right

Tags: css

I am trying to make this burst pattern I've created scale from 0 to 100% in the position that it is at on the page (High center). The problem is that the animation floats in from the top right into the center which is not proper. I am not sure how to make it scale in place.

This may be a bit unusual to work with because my pattern is a triangle rotated into 13 positions to create the burst pattern and therefore may be somewhat awkward to work with.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n5nk76y9kj

Comment: use this one **.top-right{ top: -100%; left: 100%; }**

Comment: Where? I am not seeing where that works.